# Prove or disprove : If $E[Y|X]=X$, $E[X|Y]=Y$, and both $E[X^2]\mbox{ and }E[Y^2]$ are finite, then $P[X=Y]=1$.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> Prove or disprove : If $E[Y|X]=X$, $E[X|Y]=Y$, and both $E[X^2]\mbox{ and }E[Y^2]$ are finite, then $P[X=Y]=1$. (Possible Hint: $P[X=Y]=1\mbox{ if }\operatorname{var}[X-Y]=0$)

Basically I need prove that $E[(X-Y)^2] = E[(X-Y)]^2$.

I don't have ideas. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Note this is the easy version of this result: the conclusion holds without the $L^2$ assumptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$E[(X-Y)^2]= E[X^2] -2 E[XY] + E[Y^2]$ and by the power-property of conditional
expectations, ''pulling out known factors'', and the hypothesis we have $E[XY]= E[E[XY|X]] = E[X E[Y|X]] =E[X^2]$. Changing the roles of $X$ and $Y$ we also get $E[XY]=E[Y^2]$. Thus, $E[(X-Y)^2]=0$.

EDIT. The argument can be completed as follows: $Z=(X-Y)^2$ is a non-negative random variable whose expectation is $0$ and this implies $Z=0$ almost surely.
Thus, $P[X=Y]=P[Z=0]=1$.

Comment: How does this prove that the variance is $0$, since $\operatorname{Var}[X-Y]$ is in general not equal to $E[(X-Y)^2]$, is it? In fact, $$Var(X-Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)-2Cov(X,Y)=E[X^2]-(E[X]^2)+E[Y^2]-(E[Y]^2)-2E[XY]+2E[X]E[Y]=-(E[X]^2)-(E[Y]^2) + 2E[X]E[Y]=2E[X]E[Y]-(E[X])^2-(E[Y])^2$$

Comment: @Jochen      To be honest I have the same question Why $Var(x-y)=[E(X−Y)^2]$ ???

Comment: $Var(X-Y) = E[(X-Y)^2]$ because the second term, $E[(X-Y)]^2$ is 0 since E(X) = E(Y) due to the law of total expectation ${E(X) = E[E(X|Y)] = E[Y]}$.

Comment: @Avraham        :O , thanks you very much , now I understand :)

Comment: @Avraham Ah ok, good point. Then my computation also gives $Var(X-Y)=0$. Nice one!

Comment: How are you writing $E[XY]=E[E[XY|X]]$